# Get the width of a JPanel without the Border

Tags: java, swing, width, border, insets

I have a JPanel with a null layout (this should stay), and a simple Etched Border. 
Now i want to set the location of a button at the deapest point; for this i need the width of the border. How can i get this?  `Component.insets().bottom` works fine, but this method is deprecated. Is there something newer? Thanks!

Edit: sry for my english. 
And Thanks for downvotingm.. -.-

Comment: *"I have a JPanel with a null layout (this should stay)"*  Beg to differ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int base = myComponent.getInsets().bottom;
```

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#insets%28%29)

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by getInsets().

Swing was designed to use [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Definitely better to use one for positioning & sizing components. It *should* remove the necessity to determine the base location of your component.

Comment: oooh... then insets() was just replaced by getInsets() ? o.O really strange.. but thank you :)

Comment: Yes but i need the null layout in this case.

Comment: @GFP no, you don't "need" a null layout - that's true to at least third approximation. What you doing is **exactly** the responsibility of a LayoutManager. Review your layout requirements and search a manager that suits your needs.

Comment: Okay okay ill end this discussion: I WANT to use a null layout here. I have a frame that has the sizeo ff 400x300, and its undecorated. No one can change the size or move it. And no one has a smaller screen than this.

Comment: @GFP still there are many things that can change (font f.i.) - you make your own life miserable, and deserve it <g>

Comment: and still its my thing to use the null layout or not.